# How can I use a regex in php to get characters at the end of a string

Tags: php, regex

**I would like to parse a string and get characters from the end back to the first slash in the string.** The string may change.

An example may be:

```
'string4\string3\string2\string1'
```

And I would want `string1` from this example.

Another example string is:

```
'string3\string2\string1'
```

And I would like to get `string1` from this example. Can this be done in php using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Just break the string apart by the `\` character and get the last part:

```
$parts = explode('\\', $string);
echo $parts[count($parts) - 1];
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/D3ucVw)